# How can I store each certain ticks in an arrangement in Netlogo

Tags: arrays, netlogo

I'm new in Netlogo and I need some help.

I am working on a small simulation and I need to store the values of a variable that constantly change in an array every 10 ticks.

I understand it is possible to use extensions [array], but I really don't understand how to solve my problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly is the thing that you are asking here? Do you need help with storing variables in an array or do you need help with doing so depending on the tick? 
What have you already tried? And does it need to be an array or is a list also fine? These are easier to work with in Netlogo. To my knowledge, arrays don't allow you to easily append values to the end without a detour, whereas with lists that is no problem. Do the values you store need to replace the previous set of values or do you want to add them to the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short code snippet illustrates how you can add a value to a list every few ticks. The value changes every tick but is only added to the list every 10 ticks. I use `ticks mod 10` to calculate the residue of dividing ticks by 10. This value is 0 every 10 ticks. To append an item to a list, you can use `lput` or `fput`.

```
globals [your-list]

to setup
  
  set your-list []
  reset-ticks
  
end

to go

  let your-item random-float 1
  if ticks mod 10 = 0 [set your-list lput your-item your-list]

  tick
  
end
```

Comment: @DannyPaez You're welcome. Could you please accept the answer? That way, other people know that the question is solved and won't needlessly come checking it again